# How to create my own ref label system?

Tags: macros, hyperref, cross-referencing, indexing

I want to add a hyperlink to sections where a file is discussed. Additionally the usage should be added to the index. In principle this is very close to the label ref system.

A simple approach would be this

```
\newcommand{\labelfile}[1]{%
\hypertarget{file:#1}{}%
\index{file!#1}%
\csname doc@file@#1\endcsname%
}

\newcommand{\file}[1]{%
\ifcsdef{doc@file@#1}{%
\hyperlink{file:#1}{#1}%
}{%
\texttt{#1}%
}%
}
```

which would be used as

```
\section{about links in pdf}    
The code is in \file{preamble/hyperref.tex}
...
\section{preamble/hyperref.tex}
\labelfile{preamble/hyperref.tex}
```

It however does not work, because the label is created after the ref command. So I need to add everything to the aux file and read it again. However how do I implement that?

Additionally I would like to have everything in the index as

```
files
   preamble
      hyperref.tex
```

That however requires to pass it to the index as

```
\index{files!preamble!hyperref.tex}
```

I however have it as

```
\index{files!preamble/hyperref.tex}
```

how can I replace the char `/` with `!` ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the normal \label/\ref system for this. The link is then done with

```
\hyperref[label]{text}
```

**Discussion \label setting and destination name**

A `\label` uses the currently active anchor (usually, the last anchor set) when
it writes the reference data into the `.aux` file. The example does not show
whether the target for `preamble/hyperref.tex` should be the section with the
same title or it should moved below to the position of `\labelfile`. In the first
case, the part in the solution example file between the `%%%` markers should be:

```
%%%
\newcommand*{\labelfile}[1]{%
  \label{file:#1}%
  \index{file!#1@\string\FileName{#1}}%
}
%%%
```

If `\labelfile` should set its own anchor, but the destination name does not
matter, then the part between the `%%%` markers should be:

```
%%%
\newcommand*{\labelfile}[1]{%
  \phantomsection
  \label{file:#1}%
  \index{file!#1@\string\FileName{#1}}%
}
%%%
```

The anchor setting is done by `\phantomsection`.

The full variant below also controls the destination name. It uses the fact that `hyperref`'s
redefinition of `\refstepcounter` sets an anchor. (With default options) the destination
name is constructed from the counter name and the counter value. Different destinations must not share the same destination name. A problem is that `\the<counter>` is not always unique.
Therefore `hyperref` uses `\theH<counter>` for destination names. The file names here
are unique because they are also used for `\label`. `\thefile` shows the "file number"
that is not needed here (at end of document it could be used to get the maximum number of files). `\theHfile` is completely different, it shows the file name and the destination
name would be `file.example.tex` for file `example.tex`, the first part `file` is the
counter name, the following dot is hardwired, and the remaining part is the file name.

**File name formatting**

File names can be formatted in many ways. There are packages that deal with
hyphenation, font settings, … As an example, I have used package `url` to
define a formatting command `\FileName` and also added this to the index
entry to show the special syntax of the index entries. I assume that the
file names does not contain too fancy characters. Otherwise some extra
work would be needed to deal with the problematic characters.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{url}
\DeclareUrlCommand{\FileName}{\urlstyle{tt}}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

%%%
\newcounter{file}
\providecommand*{\theHfile}{\thefile}

\newcommand*{\labelfile}[1]{%
  \renewcommand*{\theHfile}{#1}%
  \refstepcounter{file}%
  \label{file:#1}%
  \index{file!#1@\string\FileName{#1}}%
}
%%%

\newcommand*{\file}[1]{%
  \hyperref[file:#1]{\FileName{#1}}%
} 

\begin{document}

\section{about links in pdf}    
The code is in \file{preamble/hyperref.tex}
\dots
\section{preamble/hyperref.tex}
\labelfile{preamble/hyperref.tex}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice documentation of the answer! However I do not understand why the new `\theHFile` counter is required, since it is not used in `\file`.

Comment: Reading your [profile](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967/heiko-oberdiek) (member for 9 days, 1,971 reputation, 13 silver, 29 bronze badges) I have no doubt that you are THE Heiko Oberdiek. Would you like to add your packages to the list at [who-are-the-package-maintainers-here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/who-are-the-package-maintainers-here), please?

Comment: Sorry, no (currently at least). I am a novice here at this site with just a few days experience in answering
some older and some newer questions. IMHO a maintainer package list should contain a clear and
easy way to contact the maintainer. Not everything makes sense to be handled in Q/A-form.
Third, there are too many packages. I can handle them only with some kind of automation. Manually
redundant edits of meta data are the worst enemy. I have the greatest respect for Robin Fairbairns, who maintains
the TeX Catalogue with much endurance. If someone has time to offer, please help him.